# knockout template parsing of json data is not working

Tags: json, knockout.js

Please check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/TribhuwanD/H2EWw/) is not working, i have no idea what is wrong in my code.
I am trying to create a blog application, which have title, description and comments, but i am not getting proper output.

```
<h4>Title</h4>
<label data-bind="value: title" />
<h4>Description</h4>
<label data-bind="value: description" />
<h4>Comments</h4>
<p data-bind="foreach: comments">
    <label data-bind="value: commenter" /><br>
    <label data-bind="value: comment" /><br>
</p>​


var data = {"title": "blog1",
                "description": "Description1",
                "comments": [{"commenter": "commenter1", "comment": "comment1"},
                             {"commenter": "commenter2", "comment": "comment2"},
                             {"commenter": "commenter3", "comment": "comment3"},
                             {"commenter": "commenter4", "comment": "comment4"}]};
    function Comment(data) {
        this.commenter = ko.observable(data.commenter);
        this.comment = ko.observable(data.comment);
    }
    function BlogViewModel(data) {
        var self = data;
        self.title = data.title;
        self.description = data.description;
        self.comments = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(data.comments, function (com) {
            return new Comment(com.commenter, com.comment);
        }));
    }
    ko.applyBindings(new BlogViewModel(data));
​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple problems with your code some are related to KnockOut some of them are not:

Which are not related to KO:

- In `BlogViewModel` the `self` variable should hold `this` not the `data` parameter: so it should be `var self = this;`
- Your comment mapping is wrong: the `new Comment(com.commenter, com.comment)` should be `new Comment(com)`

Which are related to KO:

- The `value` binding is used for `input` elements, you have labels so you need to use the [text binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/text-binding.html) instead. E.g `data-bind="text: title"`
- KO needs valid html. Because the self-closing `label` tag is not valid you need to add the closing tags to your labels e.g `<label data-bind="text: description"></label>`

Here is a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nPtmk/) containg all the fixes.